# My own linux Chorded keyboard driver and interface to my embedded application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I wan to develop my own keypad driver to my own keypad.  I have to used GPIO to identify Key Events and used I2c to get  scan code.
I am going to develop keypad driver like this.

```
#include <linux/gpio.h> 
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

#define GPIO 1 //gpio PIN
...
if(gpio_request(GPIO, "Description")){
    Exception
}

gpio_direction_input(GPIO);
...
int irq = 0;
if((irq = gpio_to_irq(GPIO)) < 0 ){
    Exception
}
…

int init_module(){
    int result = request_irq(GPIO, handler_func, IRQF_TRIGGER_LOW,"Description", "Device id");
    if(result){
        Exception
    }
}

void handler_func(...){
    //get scan code via i2c
}
```

I need to develop an interface and have to handle following operations
  In my keypad, print as "1abc" on the [KEY1] .
  1. When press key, display 1st Characters as it is -> "1"
  2. Special  key combinations are used to input other 3 characters
     Eg:
          key input operations as follows;
          KEY1 (direct press) should display "1"
          F1 + KEY1 (simultaneous press) should display "a"
          F2 + KEY1 (simultaneous press) should display "b"
          F3 + KEY1 (simultaneous press) should display "c"

My problem is how should I develop this interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better follow Analog devices' Keyboard and GPIO Linux Driver. I'm going to link you to some GPIO drivers.

This driver included these features

- Configurable keypad size matrix (rows, columns).
- Support for switch events.
- automatic key repeat.
- Lock/Unlock key feature.

[ADP5588 Keyboard - GPIO Linux Driver](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/input-keyboard/adp5588)

[ADP5589 Keyboard - GPIO Linux Driver](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/input-keyboard/adp5589)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is more helpful to me

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague, so I'm going to link you to some pages that describe making such input devices:

- [Steve Mann's septambic keyer](http://wearcam.org/septambi/)
- [Building and using a 7 key chording keyboard](http://chorder.cs.vassar.edu/)

What is important for chording is to separate a *key press* from a *key release*. These actions send separate [scancodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode), and [most keyboards use them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#Control_processor).

If you are specifically interested in the logic, then reading the [chorded keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard) wikipedia article may be helpful:

> In Engelbart's original mapping, he used five keys: 1,2,4,8,16. The
>   keys were mapped as follows: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, and so on. If
>   the user pressed keys 1 + 2 = 3 simultaneously the letter "c"
>   appeared.

What you need to do is figure out which character is desired by looking at the combination of keys that are pressed down, but only send the character when all keys are *released*.

So if I pressed keys 1 and 2, then the bits for key 1 and key 2 are set, but the character is only determined and sent when I release all keys, at which point all the key bits are reset.

That is but one way to do it. It's your system, and you can make it arbitrarily complex.

Maybe you want to base it on [n-gram frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) and send character phrases instead of single characters. Maybe you want to base it on sequences of letters pressed and released, with arbitrary chord sequence termination, rather than when you release all keys. It's up to you.

If you are using a normal keypad, and not one you built yourself, watch out for problems with [key rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29). Basically, most keyboards have limits on which keys can be pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the kernel version and the architecture that you are using.

If you are using an architecture that is supported in 3.1 or later then you can use the gpio-keys driver to create a keyboard event device file that you can configure in the OpenFirmware device tree and then read from userspace. The advantages of this approach over the approach suggested in the OP are that you do not have to write any new kernel code, and you can write your higher level driver entirely in userspace using a loop that does a blocking read on the device event file. (Now I realize that "not have to write any new kernel code" isn't nearly as cool as writing your own kernel module, so this might not be seen as an advantage by everyone ;-)

Even if you are using an older kernel, you can still use the gpio_keys driver using the older "board file" configuration approach used in the ADP5589 gpio driver suggested as a solution by [user3072817](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072817/user3072817). This still gives you the advantage of a device file on which you can do a blocking read from userspace.

To use the newer gpio-key approach you need to add a gpio-keys section to the device tree for your board, which should be located in `arch/<your arch>/boot/dts`. The syntax for the binding is specified in [gpio_keys.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio_keys.txt). You can see an example gpio-keys device tree configuration for the Manga touchscreen on the BeagleBone [here](http://hipstercircuits.com/category/device-tree/). This example also shows a gpio-key userspace driver, written in Python. Remember to compile your kernel with `CONFIG_KEYBOARD_GPIO`.